# How is the official Debian Live-CD image built?

Tags: debian, livecd

From [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LiveCD) it looks like Debian Live-CD is built using live-build. However I couldn't find the source code (live-build configurations). Also this wiki was last edited in 2015. Could someone point me to the least source code that builds Debian live-cd?

Comment: I have found the [GitLab Repo](https://salsa.debian.org/live-team/live-build) for Live-Build. Live-Build is a set of scripts utilizing `debootstrap` to create the Debian Live Boot. The source code would be the source code of each individual tool, bash script, and program that you could choose to use or not use. Also I would like to mention, many pages of the Debian wiki may be "old", however if nothing has changed about that topic since then does the page need to updated?

Comment: It looks like this is the source code for live-build itself. What I had in mind was the source configuration that uses live-build to build official Debian live cd. In particular, I'm having some trouble with some configuration in live-build and I hope to see how official release is configured.

Comment: Here is the [Live Systems Manual](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/index.en.html) as well as information on how to contact the devs [here](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/). Please [update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/501744/edit) your post with more context as to what specific issues you are encountering. Thank you.